# Archlinux installation: File system 'ext2' does't support embedding

Tags: linux, grub, arch-linux

I am installing ArchLinux from archlinux-2017.05.01-x86_64.iso to VMware VM per this [guide](http://lifehacker.com/5680453/build-a-killer-customized-arch-linux-installation-and-learn-all-about-linux-in-the-process).

```
uname -a
Linux archiso 4.10.13-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT 
grub-install --target=i386-pc --recheck /dev/sda
warning: File system 'ext2' doesn't support embedding
warning: Embedding is not possible. GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists
```

The whole error stack:[image]

Mount output : [image]

Fstab:[image]

I can see the `--target` has many different options but which one I will need to use?

Comment: `cat /etc/fstab` https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2mWB.png

Comment: Have you tried running it without specifying the target? I normally just run grub-install, and the location.

Comment: It appears you wanted to link to the guide you used, but then forgot the actual linking.

Comment: @DanielB the link has been added.   
djsmiley2k yes the issue is the same: http://prntscr.com/fddc51

Comment: Grub requires a few unused sectors after the MBR to store its second stage. If those sectors are not available it'll give `doesn't support embedding` error

Comment: He doesn’t even have a partition table. @feedthemachine I recommend you ditch that guide for now and use the [Arch Installation Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide). It’s less talking and more facts. After you can boot, you may return to the lifehacker guide.

Comment: Ouch... And you are on 32-bit Arch. Be prepared for several reinstalls a year. It will updates and then fail to boot about every 6 months or so. After the third one I stopped building 32-bit images for testing.

Comment: While I don’t have any problems with 32-bit Arch, it is nonetheless a valid point. [Support for 32-bit will be dropped soon.](https://www.archlinux.org/news/phasing-out-i686-support/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have formatted the entire disk as ext4, without partitioning it. This is evidently not compatible with GRUB.

Partition your disk using MBR or GPT. With GPT, you have to add a small (1 MiB) partition of type “BIOS Boot Partition”. The `gdisk` code for this type is `ef02`.

For BIOS boot, at the very least, you’ll want the following partitions:

- sda1: 1 MB BIOS Boot Partition
- sda2: Swap, size as needed
- sda3: Root, rest of disk

To create those using `gdisk`:

- `o`: Create new GPT scheme
- `n`, `1`, accept default, `+1M`, `EF02`: Create BIOS Boot partition
- `n`, `2`, accept default, `+1G`, `8200`: Create swap partition (1 GB)
- `n`, `3`, accept default, accept default, accept default: Create root partition
- `w`: Write to disk and exit

You can then continue installing.

Comment: BIOS Boot Partition is only required for booting GPT on BIOS. If the OP's mainboard supports UEFI it's not needed

Comment: I know. However, if he explicitly tells GRUB to use `i386-pc`, it is required. For UEFI, an EFI System Partition is required.

Comment: Strange but I created `ef02` disk as follows: http://prntscr.com/feznr8 but still cannot do `grub-install`

Comment: Yeah, that’s not GPT. I’ve added specific instructions on how to create a usable GPT scheme.